# Charles is not registering the localhost charles traffic

Tags: localhost, charles-proxy

I am using charles to get the traffic of some devices and it is working corectly. But for some reason it is not registering the traffic from the browser, specifically from localhost, for example:

http://localhost:8080/apis/v1/homefeed?index=mobilefrontpage&hsvPubkey=espn-en-homescreen-video-qa&platform=android&profile=sportscenter_v1&locale=co&version=21&device=handset&lang=en&region=us&appName=espnapp&swid=57cb001d-71cb-4e37-a7a0-265d275e6752&enableHero=true&authorizedNetworks=buzzerbeater,espn1,espn2,espn3,espn_free,espnclassic,espndeportes,espnews,espnu,goalline,longhorn,sec&hasMVPDAuthedEver=false&freePreviewTimeAvailable=10&isAuthenticated=false&content=26199860

This petitiion is not registered in charles and I need to mock this one with some of its internal calls, but now it is not possible, because for the charles issue.

I tried to use: http://localhost.charlesproxy.com, but I am getting a 404 issue.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using http://localhost.charlesproxy.com is the right choice. You get `404` because the expected resource in URL does not exist. It has nothing to do with Charles and HTTP proxy.

According to [Charles document](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/localhost-traffic-doesnt-appear-in-charles/):

> Some systems are hard coded to not use proxies for localhost traffic, so when you connect to http://localhost/ it doesn't show up in Charles.
>
> The workaround is to connect to http://localhost.charlesproxy.com/ instead. This points to the IP address 127.0.0.1, so it should work identically to localhost, but with the advantage that it will go through Charles.

Actually, you can use any domain that point to 127.0.0.1, not just http://localhost.charlesproxy.com. For example, I have a domain `donghz.com` which is resolved to 127.0.0.1, you can access http://donghz.com:8080/apis/v1/home... and get the same response too, with HTTP intercepted by Charles.